clang 19.1.0 rejects nested lambda with templates
The following code generates an error on clang 19.1.0, but passes on older versions, gcc and msvc (live example).
template <typename>
void func() {
    (void)[]<typename>() consteval {
        return []() {
            return 0;
        }.operator()();
    }.template operator()<void>();
}

template void func<void>();

<source>:4:16: error: cannot initialize object parameter of type 'const (lambda at <source>:4:16)' with an expression of type '(lambda at <source>:4:16)'
    4 |         return []() {
      |                ^~~~~~
    5 |             return 0;
      |             ~~~~~~~~~
    6 |         }.operator()();
      |         ~
<source>:7:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func()::(anonymous class)::operator()<void>' requested here
    7 |     }.template operator()<void>();
      |                ^
<source>:10:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func<void>' requested here
   10 | template void func<void>();
      |               ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1

Making some seemingly unrelated and small changes makes the snippet compile.
Some of the changes that each would make it compile:

Turning func into a non-templated function
Removing the template (and changing the .template operator() to just .operator()) from the outer lambda
Changing the inner lambdas .operator()() to just ()
Removing the consteval
Storing the result of the the call to the inner lambda in a variable and returning that variable
Storing the inner lambda in a variable and returning the result of calling this lambdas .operator()

Even though the rejected code is cryptic and probably not something likely to be seen in some production code, I don't see any errors in it. The fact that other compilers allow it (and even older clang versions) makes me be pretty sure that this is just a compiler bug. Is there an explanation to this behavior or is it just a bug as I am suspecting?

When I tried to simplify the code (by removing .operator() and just use () to immediately invoke the lambda it works again : https://godbolt.org/z/YGonjoazz. Not sure why clang would have issues though (can be a bug)

@PepijnKramer Yes, I know. I have that already written in my post ("Changing the inner lambdas .operator()() to just ()"). I am not searching for workarounds, as I already have many. I am just wondering why it doesn't work, but all the other options I have listed do work.

Transformation of code to have a constexpr lambda object leads to error call to consteval function 'func()::(anonymous class)::operator()<void>' is not a constant expression. I have suspicion that somehow explicit call to operator with nothing depending on template argument doesn't match clang's inner requirement to be consteval
